# Android: I cannot read a file from internal storage after writing

Tags: java, android, gson, android-file

In my android application, I serialize the  big object and write it into the file. I am using gson and I store the files into internal storage.

If I write a file and exit my application, then if I login in and  try to read this file, I do not come across any problem.

If I write a file and try to read this file without existing application, I cannot deserialize object properly. My application does not crash and also I do not see anything in  log but my object does not contain proper data.

These are my read and write functions;

```
public static void objecttoJson(MyObject myObject,String fileName){

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonString = gson.toJson(myObject);
    try {

        FileOutputStream fos =  MyApplication.getMyContext().openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(jsonString.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


public static MyObject jsontoObject(String fileName) {

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    String mystring = null;

    try {    
        FileInputStream fis =   MyApplication.getMyContext().openFileInput(fileName);
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            if(result == null){
                mystring  = line;
            }
            else{
            mystring.concat(line);
            }
        }

        MyObject obj = gson.fromJson(mystring, MyObject.class);

        fos.close();
        return obj;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}
```

I do not know  why my code works when I exit application. I checked my other classes and read internal storage in android official site but I did not find anything,I suspect that there is a kind of lock when I start to write.

Comment: Before `fos.close()`, add `fos.flush()` and `fos.getFd().sync()`, and see if that helps.

Comment: There is no methods  flush and getFd  for FileInputStream

Comment: Since `fos` is not a `FileInputStream`, I fail to see the problem. `fos` is a `FileOutputStream`, and `flush()` and `getFd()` are methods on `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: I found getFD() method but flush is not available for FileInputStream

Comment: I will try flush for writer

Comment: I guess for clarity you could rename `fos` to `fis` in `jsontoObject`.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I renamed it.